# how to store multiple products in add to carts using session in codeigniter-3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to add multiple product in SESSION when user click on add to cart button and how to fetch all product from SESSION using codeigniter...please help.

```
if ($_POST) 
        {
            $sessionData = [
                    'p_id' => $this->input->post('pid'),
                    'p_name' => $this->input->post('pname'),
                    'p_qty' =>$this->input->post('viewproduct_details_qty'),
                    'p_price' => $this->input->post('pprice'),
                    'p_discount' => $this->input->post('pdiscount'),
                    'p_dprice' => $this->input->post('pdiscountprice'),
                    'p_imagename' => $this->input->post('pimagename'),
                ];

            echo "<pre>";    
            print_r($sessionData);

            $p_session = $this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
            //$this->load->view("add_to_cart_page_session");    

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use Below code :**

First You have to load session library in : **config->autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session'); // Load session Library in autoload.php


if ($_POST) 
        {
            $sessionData = [
                    'p_id' => $this->input->post('pid'),
                    'p_name' => $this->input->post('pname'),
                    'p_qty' =>$this->input->post('viewproduct_details_qty'),
                    'p_price' => $this->input->post('pprice'),
                    'p_discount' => $this->input->post('pdiscount'),
                    'p_dprice' => $this->input->post('pdiscountprice'),
                    'p_imagename' => $this->input->post('pimagename'),
                ];

            echo "<pre>";    
            print_r($sessionData);

            $this->session->set_userdata('YOUR_SESSION_NAME',$sessionData); // You have to give session name
             print_r($this->session->userdata('YOUR_SESSION_NAME')); // You Can Access Session by name

            //$this->load->view("add_to_cart_page_session");    

        }
```